# mysql directory grow to 246G after one query, which failed due to table is full

Tags: mysql, innodb, join

I was trying to run the following statement with the hope to create a join of two existing tables.

```
create table CRS_PAIR
select concat_ws(',', a.TESTING_ID, b.TRAINING_ID, a.TESTING_C) as k, concat_ws(',', a.YTG, b.YTG) as YTG
from CRS_TESTING a, CRS_TRAINING b
where a.TESTING_C=b.TRAINING_C;
```

Currently the size of these two tables are:

```
mysql> SELECT table_name, round(((data_length + index_length) / (1024*1024)),2) as "size in megs" FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "crs";
+----------------+---------------+
| table_name     | size in megs  |
+----------------+---------------+
| CRS_TESTING    |         36.59 |
| CRS_TRAINING   |        202.92 |
+----------------+---------------+
```

After a little over a day, The query finished and I got the following result.

```
140330  2:53:50 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: The table 'CRS_PAIR' is full
140330  2:53:54  InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is 9434006,
InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity 9433498.
InnoDB: If you are using big BLOB or TEXT rows, you must set the
InnoDB: combined size of log files at least 10 times bigger than the
InnoDB: largest such row.
```

It turned out that the size of `/var/lib/mysql` has grown to 246GB in disk space, and the disk run out of space. However, for some reason, the `CRS_PAIR` table does not show up in the shell. Even when I try to get the size of all databases.

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / (1024 * 1024) "Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ; 
+--------------------+----------------------+
| Data Base Name     | Data Base Size in MB |
+--------------------+----------------------+
| crs                |            1426.4531 |
| information_schema |               0.0088 |
| mysql              |               0.6453 |
| performance_schema |               0.0000 |
+--------------------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.74 sec)
```

This is the show tables command.

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_crs  |
+----------------+
| CRS_TESTING    |
| CRS_TRAINING   |
 some other tables
+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`CRS_PAIR` is not there.

May I ask if anyone can help me figure out where this mysterious table went to so that I can clean up my disk space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table simply does not exist. How can you verify this ?

Goto the operating system and run the following

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/crs
ls -l CRS_PAIR.frm
```

If that file does not exist, the table does not exist. If that is the case, then what's all that 246G bloated space ? You need to look the following

## InnoDB Architecture

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Take a closer look at ibdata1 ( system tablespace ). What does it comprise of ?

- Data Dictionary
- Double Write Buffer (support data consistency; used for Crash Recovery)
- Insert Buffer (Buffers Changes to Secondary Non-Unique Indexes)
- Rollback Segments
- Undo Space **(where the most uncontrolled growth can happen)**

What you are the victim of is a large transaction that cannot be rolled back effectively.

I discussed InnoDB wild growth back on April 23, 2013 : [How can Innodb ibdata1 file grows by 5X even with innodb_file_per_table set?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40730/how-can-innodb-ibdata1-file-grows-by-5x-even-with-innodb-file-per-table-set/40734#40734)

You are probably wondering....

## But I got a Table Full Error !!!

Think about what you were doing

- You create an empty InnoDB table via DDL (it's technically a temp table at this point)
- You attempted to load that empty table with 246G of BLOB/TEXT. There are tons of transactional records (for MVCC and Transaction Isolation Support) being accumulated in the interim.
- Since you logically ran out of space due to BLOB/TEXT records in a single transaction, the query would have to rollback and the temp table would vanish, leaving no `.frm` to show for it.. What you are left with is a 246G undo log entry that could not hold records as wide as your query demands. InnoDB is notorious for not reclaiming space ([See my very first StackOverflow post ever from `October 29, 2010` on how to reclaim that wasted space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)).

## CAVEAT #1

Table Full Errors for InnoDB is not that far-fetched because it is a logical failure to manipulate the Storage Engine. In your case, it would be due to BLOB/TEXT fields passing through logs and a Log Buffer that simply not big enough. I have another post about how you can get a "Table Full" Error when consuming all the Rollback Segments ([How to solve "The table ... is full" with "innodb_file_per_table"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/how-to-solve-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table/43577#43577))

## CAVEAT #2

If you insist on running that query and trying to make the table, you will have to expand the Transaction Logs ([**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)) and the Log Buffer Size ([innodb_log_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size)) (Look back at the InnoDB Architecture at the Log Buffer and the two Log Files).

- [My Post about doing so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/mysql-gives-out-of-memory-error-when-inserting-a-large-file-from-where-is-thi/2300#2300)
- [Where my inspiration for that post came from (someone else's 5 years old post)](https://serverfault.com/questions/3952/what-should-i-know-before-going-live-with-an-innodb-database/3979#3979)