# The table is full - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.2

I am getting the following error whist trying to execute a long running query.

> The table 'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp#sql1664_349_19be' is full

The C drive (NTFS) on the server has 135GB free space.
The D drive (NTFS) which holds the data has 365GB free out of 800GB.

The server has 32GB RAM.

The query I am running is reasonably simple but it is run against 61 million rows.

I have 18 indexes on tblinvoice and the table is INNODB.

```
SELECT
    InvoiceNo,
    NetAmountAbs,
    InvoiceDate
  FROM tblinvoice
  WHERE GrossAmountAbs >= 200
  GROUP BY InvoiceNo,
           NetAmountAbs,
           InvoiceDate
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN NetAmount_Doc >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
  AND MIN(AccountNumber) != MAX(AccountNumber)
  AND MAX(GrossAmountAbs) != MIN(GrossAmountAbs)
  AND MAX(ImportID) = 2
```

This is my.ini file

```
[mysqld] 
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1 
datadir=E:/MariaDB 10.2.8
port=3306 
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
default_storage_engine=innodb 
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25000M
character-set-server=utf8 
innodb_io_capacity=200
innodb_read_io_threads=64 
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_write_io_threads=64 
max_connections=1000
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50 
lower_case_table_names=2
event_scheduler=on 
character-set-server=utf8 
max_allowed_packet=100M
connect_timeout=10 
innodb-log-file-size=1G
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G 
[client] 
port=3306 
plugin-dir=C:/ProgramFiles/MariaDB 10.2/lib/plugin
```

Thanks

**EDIT:** Updated my.ini with suggested changes to innodb-log-file-size,
    innodb_log_buffer_size,
    tmp_table_size,
    max_heap_table_size,

Comment: This article probably has your answer. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: I have looked at that document and edited my post to include some more information. I cannot see a reason why the query wouldn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Is it innodb or myisam? I'd look at settings for your TempDB too. It feels to me like your query is trying to store all of the data into a temp table and the temp table reaches a limit and cannot grow anymore. Whether that temp table is inno or myisam would prompt where you go next for evaluating the source of the issue.

Comment: It's an innodb table - I will update my post

Comment: Tblinvoice and the temp are both inno?

Comment: How do I check what the TempDB table engine is?

Comment: The global variable `internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine` should tell you, I imagine you are innodb though, that appears to be the default. Next I'd check the `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` global variable settings.

Comment: There is a reply from Bill Karwin on this answer that talks about altering those settings in the scope of the session to test and have limited impact on production. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308536/5149122

Comment: The closest variable I have to internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine is 'default_tmp_storage_engine' which is blank. max_heap_table_size = 16777216, tmp_table_size=16777216. As far as I know I'm not using MEMORY storage engine. Does a tmp table use MEMORY engine by default?

Comment: @skeldave  Since this effort is on a backup database, max_connections=12  # from 1000 for this backup environment will help free some RAM.  Bumping up innodb_io_capacity_max and innodb_io_capacity would not hurt either.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';`  Is that directory on the `C:` drive?  `datadir=E:/MariaDB 10.2.8` -- is there a space in that directory name?

Comment: @skeldave  Can you explain to me what these 2 lines in the query do for you?  
  AND MIN(AccountNumber) != MAX(AccountNumber)
  AND MAX(GrossAmountAbs) != MIN(GrossAmountAbs)
Thanks
Also, could you post results of EXPLAIN  SELECT .... and complete results of SHOW INDEX FROM tblInvoice?

Comment: As mentioned, this error does not mean the disk is full. However, this doesn't imply that the disk isn't full. When the disk is indeed full, you'd get exactly this message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do not get fooled by the error message.

Note that the error is `table is full`. It does not say `disk is full`.

What would create a `table is full` condition ?

It has to do with the changes that are pouring into the rollback segments for a transaction.

I have addressed this many times

- `May 31, 2013` : [How to solve "The table ... is full" with "innodb_file_per_table"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/how-to-solve-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table/43577#43577)
- `Mar 31, 2014` : [mysql directory grow to 246G after one query, which failed due to table is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62107/mysql-directory-grow-to-246g-after-one-query-which-failed-due-to-table-is-full/62108#62108)
- `Jun 16, 2014` : [MySQL Index creation failing on table is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68319/mysql-index-creation-failing-on-table-is-full/68326#68326)
- `Apr 07, 2015` : [MySQL query INSERT INTO ... failed - The Table "x" is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97246/mysql-query-insert-into-failed-the-table-x-is-full/97252#97252)

It appears that one of the following occurred

- The `SELECT` was in the middle of a transaction
- The `SELECT` attempted to hold too much rollback info in the face of  many transactions

In either case, the `tblinvoice` table probably had so many changes pending that the `SELECT` just had to give up. This could have caused all write transactions against `tblinvoice` to rollback.

If you were running this `SELECT` on a busy Master with lots of writes against `tblinvoice`, then I could this `SELECT` having this problem.

What you should do is set up a reporting slave (running MySQL Replication) and run this type of query on it instead on the main server.

## UPDATE 2018-02-27 10:10 EDT

Your problem may be the amount of RAM free.

You currently have this

```
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

Try running the query again so that the temp table goes immediately to disk

```
set tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 16;
set max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 16;
SELECT
    InvoiceNo,
    NetAmountAbs,
    InvoiceDate
  FROM tblinvoice
  WHERE GrossAmountAbs >= 200
  GROUP BY InvoiceNo,
           NetAmountAbs,
           InvoiceDate
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN NetAmount_Doc >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
  AND MIN(AccountNumber) != MAX(AccountNumber)
  AND MAX(GrossAmountAbs) != MIN(GrossAmountAbs)
  AND MAX(ImportID) = 2;
```

Keep watch on the `C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local` folder. Watch the temp file that shows up in that folder. What I am hoping is that the temp table will reach the needed size on disk. Why ?

**With `tmp_table_size=2G` and `max_heap_table_size=2G`, the temp table has to reach 2G in RAM before transferring to disk**. My working theory is that you do not have 2GB of RAM free (We are talking Windows, right ???). This is why I am suggesting lowering these to 16M (which is the default value anyway). ***Give it a try !!!***

Comment: Hi, I am doing this query on a backup of the database so there are no writes to tblinvoice. I am running the query by itself outside of any explicit transaction and I am using innodb_file_per_table. I have read the posts and made the innodb_log_file_size=1G and innodb_log_buffer_size=64M and it still fails. What is the next thing you'd recommend. Thanks

Comment: I have already read that having a large ibdata1 file is bad. Mine is currently 34GB. Should I look at adding ibdata2 according to your 2013 post?

Comment: In my 2013 post, the client had 106GB free inside `ibdata1/ibdata2` out of 2TB and still ran out of room for the undo log. Adding ibdata3 to the `innodb_data_file_path` along with `:autoextend` allowed for larger undo logs, thus it was the solution. Look for `innodb_data_file_path`. If `autoextend` is already there, then there may be another issue. If Windows caps the largest file at 32GB, then adding `ibdata2` may be your solution. Give it a try and see.

Comment: I added an ibdata2 file and I still get the table is full error. innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:34025472K;ibdata2:10M:autoextend. Any suggestions as to what I can do next? Thanks.

Comment: That seems to be the problem! Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

Those are dangerously large.  Keep them to no more than about 1% of RAM -- about 300M.  Those settings are used in tmp tables inside complex `SELECTs`; your query is such.  If several complex queries are running at the same time, several *RAM* allocations of 2GB could be happening simultaneously, thereby blowing out RAM.

`Temp#sql1664_349_19be` looks like such a tmp table name.

`ibdata1` can be arbitrarily large -- limited only by disk space (and some really big hard limit, in the terabytes, or an OS limit).  Did you have `autoextend` on `ibdata1`?  `34025472K` is more than 32G, so I don't see it as being an OS limit.

It might be useful to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think locating big amount of RAM to MySQL parameters like,

```
sort_buffer_size=
join_buffer_size=
read_buffer_size=
read_rnd_buffer_size
tmp_table_size
max_heap_table_size
```

, is a good idea, what I know is reserving big size of RAM is a slow process, so big amount of values will slow down MySQL, and this is what I found on previous tests, so even if the system has plenty of RAM, I don't think locating high amount of RAM to similar parameters is a good idea.